# iPhone dev - Set position of a view in viewDidLoad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

So, in Interface Builder I have a view within the superview that contains two Image View objects. I'd like to move that view off the screen when the app launches so it can be animated to move into place. The view is described as pictureFrame in the .h file for the interface, and I have the view mapped to the outlet pictureFrame. Here is my current viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGRect theFrame = [self.pictureFrame frame];
    theFrame.origin.y = -290;
}
```

But, it doesn't seem to be working. How do I fix this?

Comment: Don't assume that -290 is off-screen. It won't be forever. Compute that number from the bounds of the screen. http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScreen_Class/Reference/UIScreen.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScreen/bounds

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You forget to set your view's frame:

```
CGRect theFrame = [self.pictureFrame frame];
    theFrame.origin.y = -290;
```

add this and you're good:

> self.pictureFrame.frame = theFrame;

Comment: I have the same problem, except that I am using a View instead of an ImageView. I have created a method that moves the View into the screen and another one to move it away (so that I can hide the View with a go-away animation). This two actions work perfectly when assigned to buttons, but they do not work when called from the viewDidLoad method. The weird thing is that if I add a NSLog after the call and ask for the view.frame.origin.y property, the float it returns is correct (I mean, the origin.y has been updated, but the view is still where I put it in the .nib file). I am using XCode 4.6.3

Comment: All right, I found the answer almost immediately. It turns out that to move a View it is better to do it in `viewDidAppear` than in `viewDidLoad` (as is perfectly explained in @rob mayoff's answer: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476227/cannot-update-view-layer-frame-in-viewdidload)).

Answer (score 1):

I tend to do these sorts of things as one liners.  I find it easier to remember what is going on when I go back and read it later.

I also prefer to #define my view offsets to keep magic numbers out of my code.

```
#define kPictureFrameHorizontalOffset -290


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.pictureFrame.frame = CGRectMake(self.pictureFrame.frame.origin.x + 0,
                                         self.pictureFrame.frame.origin.y + kPictureFrameHorizontalOffset,
                                         self.pictureFrame.frame.size.width + 0,
                                         self.pictureFrame.frame.size.height + 0);
}
```

Granted it is a bit more verbose, but it works well for me.